# set an image sent as binary data from node.js in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am retrieving an image which is stored as in binary form from mongoDB. and sending it as a json to jquery ajax. but console.log from node.js show it is fine but when request comes back to jquery ajax nothing happens, cannot see an image. And also image is saved in DB with type BUFFER. below is the code

jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: config.ipaddress+'/getCompanyImage',
    contentType: 'image/png',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.each(data, function(index, result) {
            alert('image result ' + result);
            $("#headerCompanyImage").attr("src", result);
        });

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

node.js code

```
exports.getCompanyImage = function(req,res) {
var_company.find({_id : req.session.company},function(err,company){
    company.forEach(function(companyLoop){
        console.log(companyLoop.company_image.contentType);
        console.log(companyLoop.company_image.data);
        res.contentType(companyLoop.company_image.contentType);
        res.json(companyLoop.company_image.data);
    })

  });
}
```

Comment: I think you can't return image as json... unless it's encoded as dataURL or base 64 or some other string, is that the case?

Comment: yes actually i am sending an image as json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the solution. It has to be in binary form and then convert it toString('base64') and then send the response. and now it is working

```
var img = new Buffer(companyLoop.company_image.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
res.contentType(companyLoop.company_image.contentType);
res.send(img);
```

and in jquery it would be

```
$("#headerCompanyImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data);
```